# Running gnome-keyring-daemon in CentOS?

Tags: centos, gnome-keyring

I successfully installed MySQL Workbench in Centos 6.2. When I run MySQL Workbench and try to store a password by clicking "Store in Keychain", I get the following error:

> Could not store password: The gnome-keyring-daemon application is not
>   running.

N.B: after clicking "Store in Keychain", I do enter a the MySQL user/password.

When I try to run the following `command /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon -d`, I get the following message:

> gnome-keyring-daemon: couldn't lookup ssh component setting: Failed to contact configuration server;
>
> some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP networking for
>   ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system crash. See
>   http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information.
>
> (Details -  1: Server ping error: IDL:omg.org/CORBA/COMM_FAILURE:1.0)gnome-keyring-daemon:
>
> couldn't lookup pkcs11 component setting: Failed to contact configuration
>   server; some possible causes are that you need to enable TCP/IP
>   networking for ORBit, or you have stale NFS locks due to a system
>   crash. See http://projects.gnome.org/gconf/ for information.
>
> (Details -  1: Server ping error: IDL:omg.org/CORBA/COMM_FAILURE:1.0) GNOME_KEYRING_SOCKET=/tmp/keyring-FazjOu/socket SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-FazjOu/socket.ssh GNOME_KEYRING_PID=20933

Comment: Might be useful: http://kenneho.net/2011/01/30/using-svn-client-and-gnome-keyring-in-ssh-sessions/